# Do not display empty inline-block elements with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this HTML layout:

```
<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>
<p>foo2</p><p>bar2</p>
<p></p><p></p>
<p>foo4</p><p>bar4</p>
<p></p><p></p>
```

which is styled as:

```
p{display:inline-block; width:50%;margin:0;}
p:nth-child(even){text-align:left;background:red;}
p:nth-child(odd){text-align:right;background:blue;}
```

The problem is that empty elements take space. Is it possible (*only with CSS*) to prevent the empty elements from take up vertical space?

[Here is a fiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/p7ffoywm/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`:empty` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aempty) to hide the empty elements:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j8rkLxke/)

```
p:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}

p:nth-child(even) {
  text-align: left;
  background: red;
}

p:nth-child(odd) {
  text-align: right;
  background: blue;
}
p:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>
<p>foo2</p><p>bar2</p>
<p></p><p></p>
<p>foo4</p><p>bar4</p>
<p></p><p></p>
```

Comment: Does it alse select elements with `whitespace` content?

Comment: @Ormoz Yea. It will only select the element if it doesn't contain anything.

Comment: Thanks, Great answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:empty` pseudo-class to select and hide those elements.

But you have to **be careful** while using this pseudo-class selector because this **won't work even if the element has a single space** inside.

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}
p:nth-child(even) {
  text-align: left;
  background: red;
}
p:nth-child(odd) {
  text-align: right;
  background: blue;
}
p:empty{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
<p>foo2</p>
<p>bar2</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>foo4</p>
<p>bar4</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

---

The below snippet is just to show how it doesn't select elements that aren't completely empty (devoid of spaces).

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}
p:nth-child(even) {
  text-align: left;
  background: red;
}
p:nth-child(odd) {
  text-align: right;
  background: blue;
}
p:empty{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
<p>foo2</p>
<p>bar2</p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p>foo4</p>
<p>bar4</p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D: Huh? I did try it before posting the answer and it did select the empty elements (not even a space) which has padding. Used Josh's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8rkLxke/1/) and it does hide the `p` even though there is padding.